# Decide which button has been pressed

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have the following code for creating a group of questions, however, I have run into an obstacle. I need a way to distinguish which button has been pressed, however, I'm unable to do so as all buttons are generated in a for loop:

```
tk.Label(self.canvas, text='Please choose an option below:').pack(fill='both',expand=True)
self.buttonGroup = tk.LabelFrame(self.canvas, text="Options")
self.buttonGroup.pack(fill='both',expand=True)
self.buttons = []

for i in range(0, len(options)):
    temp = tk.Button(self.buttonGroup, text=str(options[i]), bg=str(back), fg=str(fore))
    temp.pack(fill='both',expand=True)
    self.buttons.append(temp)
```

I have already read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51350849/13010024) and tried the following code:

```
temp = tk.Button(self.buttonGroup, text=str(options[i]), bg=str(back), fg=str(fore), command=lambda: self.setSelection(i))
```

However, the function just sets the selected button to the index of the last button that was set.

How can I solve this problem? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing the index as a default parameter in your lambda so that it is bound when the lambda is created, like this:

`command=lambda i=i: self.setSelection(i)`